# Accessing href parameters in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, parameters, href

How to replace $_GET with Laravel's. I'm trying to access this href parameter. I know in standard PHP you execute $_GET request followed by SQL delete query statement. In Laravel it's more difficult because it involves controllers/routes. I have a destroy route in the ProjectsController. The below link is what is displayed when i hover over the link. I got the id with Jquery and passed it through, but the problem is I want it to delete the project from database whenever this link is clicked.

```
<a href="projects/delete=31"> delete</a>
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\project;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Session;

class ProjectsController extends Controller
{



    public function destroy($id){


        $project = Project::find($id);

        $request->input('delete'); 

        $project->delete();

        Session::flash('success', 'The project was successfully deleted!');

        return redirect()->route('projects.show', $project->project_id);

    }

}
```

Comment: $id = Input::get('delete')

Comment: Quick question even though I submitted my answer below. What are you trying to achieve, `<a href="projects?delete=31">delete</a>`  or `<a href="projects/delete/31">delete</a>`?

Comment: @Gayan it's fixed by Buglinjo and <a href="projects/delete/31">delete</a>

Comment: @steven glad to hear. I modified my answer with both approaches for the completion just in case :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Route::get('projects/delete/{id}', 'ProjectsController@destroy')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

and update your href:

```
<a href="projects/delete/31"> delete</a>
```

It will work like this. Aslo you can remove that line: `$request->input('delete');`

Comment: Hello, I know about the ? sorry. I have added this to my route destroy and does nothing. I have added my controller file.

Comment: Can you edit your post and add your view, route and controller to it?

Comment: I have added my route and controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133103/discussion-between-buglinjo-and-steven).

Comment: Where will i put that -> Route::get('projects/delete/{id}', 'ProjectsController@destroy')->where('id', '[0-9]+');

Comment: in your rotes file.

Comment: Thanks for helping and fixing it!

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
<a href="projects/delete=31">delete</a> // this is wrong
```

to

**Approch 01**

```
<a href="projects?delete=31">delete</a>
```

Set your route as

```
Route::get('projects', 'ProjectsController@destroy');
```

Set your ProjectsController like

```
class ProjectsController
{
    public function destroy()
    {
        $delete = request()->get('delete');
    }
}
```

**Approch 02**

```
<a href="projects/delete/31">delete</a>
```

Set your route as

```
Route::get('projects/{id}', 'ProjectsController@destroy');
```

Set your ProjectsController like

```
class ProjectsController
{
    public function destroy($id) // $id = 31
    {
        // your code
    }
}
```

Refer [routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing) and [controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers) to get a grasp on them.

Comment: Man, you've copy-pasted answers twice here. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Change the link to:

```
<a href="/projects?delete=31"> delete</a>
```

Make sure the route looks like this:

```
Route::get('projects', ....
```

Then in you'll have an access to this parameter with `request('delete')` in a controller, model etc.

Comment: Use `request()` helper instead of `$request` variable. Or object `Request` object in the method `destroy (Request $request)`

Comment: Confused here sorry. if you can manipulate my above code then I might understand.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try like this way

```
<a href="{{ asset('projects/delete/{id}') }}">delete</a>
```

and set route

```
Route::get('/projects/delete/{id}', 'ProjectsController@delete');
```

about delete function in ProjectsController

```
public function delete($id)
{
    $projects = projects::find($id);
    $projects->delete();
    return redirect('/yourEditPage');
}
```

hope this can help you !

Answer (score 0):

Other answers has covered how you can access the get parameter via routing, which indeed answers your original question.

I would however suggest you to follow restful pattern (using `DELETE` method) when deleting things. In laravel  it's pretty simple.

**The route**

```
Route::delete('projects/{project}', 'ProjectsController@destroy')->name('projects.destroy');
```

**The controller method**

```
public function destroy(Project $project) {
    $project->delete();
    Session::flash('success', 'The project was successfully deleted!');
    return redirect()->route('projects.index');
}
```

**The template**

```
<form action="{{route('projects.destroy', ['project' => $project->id])}}" method="POST">
{{method_field('DELETE')}}
{{csrf_field()}}

<button type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```